# When using DbSet<T>.SqlQuery(), how to use named parameters?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-injection

I'm a big fan of using named parameters instead of string-based parameter injection. It's type-safe and safe against most forms of SQL injection. In old ADO.NET, I would create a SqlCommand object and a bunch of SqlParameters for my query.

```
var sSQL = "select * from Users where Name = @Name";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(conn, sSQL);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Bob");
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Now, in Entity Framework, it appears (on this link) to have regressed to a simple String.Format statement and string injection again: (simplified for discussion)

```
MyRepository.Users.SqlQuery("Select * from Users where Name = {0}", "Bob");
```

Is there a way to use named parameters with the Entity Framework DbSqlQuery class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var param = new ObjectParameter(":p0", "Bob");
MyRepository.Users.SqlQuery("Select * from Users where Name = :p0", param);
```

Comment: Where is that documented? And what name formats are allowable in the SQL Body? Can it not support the @name style?

Comment: @EricFalsken. You can see in [here in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectparameter.aspx), **this \@name style are supported**.

Comment: This totally doesn't work for me, it is not documented, and you just get `The specified parameter name ':p0' is not valid. Parameter names must begin with a letter and can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores.`

Answer (score 3):

Since I can't comment, I'm fixing the other answer:

```
var param = new ObjectParameter("p0", "Bob");
MyRepository.Users.SqlQuery("Select * from Users where Name = :p0", param);
```

You don't have to put a colon on the name when instantiating an ObjectParameter. That's why SLC got the error he mentioned in his comment.